# "import wx" fails in PySCripter

Tags: python-2.7, import, 64-bit, wxpython, pyscripter

I have a 64-bit windows 7 OS where I installed ArcGIS with 64-bit Python 2.7.
I also installed 64 pyscripter editor.
When I import wx from Python 2.7 IDE no isse - I get this:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

    >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
    >>> 
    >>> import wx
    >>> 
    >
```

When I import from PyScripter - fails I get this:

```
*** Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. ***

>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>>>
```

Anybody can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is installing to the wrong location. Normally when you install Python packages, they get installed to `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages`. Somehow you installed wxPython to `C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.3\lib\site-packages`. I would uninstall wxPython and when you re-run the wxPython installer, specify where to install it.

I should note that wxPython works fine for me on Windows 7 when it is installed in the correct location. I can import wx from both Python's interpreter and in PyScripter.